# HTML paragraph text causing image to scale when window is re-sized

Tags: html, css

I've been struggling with this for a while and just cannot get it to work.

Inside each 'article' on my webpage, I have an image on the left, and a heading over a paragraph on the right.

If I have paragraph text, the image will not scale correctly when I reduce the size of the window: https://i.stack.imgur.com/xT4bD.jpg

When the window is full sized it looks correct.

Without the paragraph text it works, until the heading does the same thing once the window is small enough.

I want the image height to always be the height of the article, but min-height: 100% doesn't work for me.

I feel like I've got a fundamental misunderstanding when it comes to css layout but I can't figure it out.
Any help would be hugely appreciated.

Code:

```css
body article{
    float: left;
    width: 74%;
    border-right: 5px solid #e05a00;
    border-left:  5px solid #e05a00;
    border-top: 5px solid #0056e0;
    border-bottom: 5px solid #0056e0;
    background-color: #333;
    color: whitesmoke;
    margin-top: 10px;
}

body article img{
    float: left;
    border-right: 2px solid #e05a00;
    border-left:  2px solid #e05a00;
    max-height: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
    min-width: 39.5%;
    max-width: 39.5%;
    object-fit: fill;
        
}



body article h2{
    font-family: arial-black;
    padding-left: 1%;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 40px;
    border-bottom: 5px solid #e05a00;
}

body article p{
    padding-right: 1%;
    padding-left: 1%;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
 <article>
        <img src="images/McLaren_570S_Spider.jpg" alt="McLaren 570S Spider" />
        <h2>McLarens new 570S Spider is 'most attainable' supercar</h2>
       
        <p>Everyone loves a good supercar: gorgeous, aerodynamic, laughably out of reach for almost everyone on the planet. We love to drool over photos of these cars, fully aware that we’ll probably never drive one. McLaren wants to change that perception with the release of the 2018 570S Spider, calling it the “most attainable” sports car ever.</p>
        
        <p>This model is the third body type in McLaren’s Sport series portfolio, which includes the 570S Coupe and the 570GT. (We last saw the 570S Coupe at the 2015 New York Auto Show, and were appropriately bowled over by it.) The 570S Spider will make its global debut at the Goodwood Festival of Speed, which will be held in the UK June 29th–July 2nd.... read more <a href="https://www.theverge.com/2017/6/14/15794904/mclaren-570s-spider-attainable-supercar-price" >on the Verge.com</a>
       
    </article>
```

Comment: I don't quite understand what your desired outcome is. Could you add an image?

Comment: I think this can be solved fairly easily, but have you thought about rearranging the structure of the elements when the design starts to break.  For Example: When the image begins to shrink, you instead stack everything in a column, Header > Image > Paragraph.  That way you get 2 different mobile and desktop layouts.

Comment: Sorry, must have removed the image link originally.
[Link](http://imgur.com/0ZDQCm5)


As you can see, the image doesn't fill the height of the article container.

Comment: it's doing what you're telling it too - you use `%` to specify height and width. Thus, changing the window size, reduces/increases the % => px... your code works as it should be doing - try pixels if you don't want to be responsive

Comment: when you reduce the size of the window how do you want the image to scale?  If it scales the way it sounds like you want it to scale the image will be distorted.  As the x axis changes what do you expect to happen to the y axis?

Comment: It scales fine when there is no paragraph text: http://imgur.com/96nV2n8 .

>>I want to stop the heading and paragraph text from going under the image when the window is scaled down -> keep the image filling the entire height of the article it is contained in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want is not technically possible. To understand why, instead of thinking about what happens when your text has 10 or 15 rows, go a bit further:

- what happens when your text has 3 pages?
- what happens when your text has 3 words?

The closest you'll get to what you want is to:

1. have two containers, side by side, with an arbitrary (pre-decided) width ratio (50% - 50%?);
2. Let the right one get its height from the text filling it.
3. Let the one in the left have the same height as the one in the right.
4. Let the image be the cropped background of the container to the left, cropping from top/bottom or left/right, depending on case.

```css
.the-layout {
  display: flex;
  max-width: 800px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.the-layout * {
  flex: 0 0 50%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.the-image {
  background: transparent url('https://unsplash.it/800/800') no-repeat 50% 50% /cover;
}
.the-text {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  padding: 0 1rem;
}
/* additionally, center it on screen when on desktop */

body {margin: 0;}
.screen-center {
  min-height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
.the-image > img {
  display: none;
}

@media (max-width: 479px) {
  .the-image > img {
    display: block;
    max-width: 100%;
  }
  .the-layout {
    flex-direction: column;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="screen-center">
<div class="the-layout">
  <div class="the-image">
    <img src="https://unsplash.it/800/800" />
  </div>
  <div class="the-text">
  <p>Warm up laptop with butt lick butt fart rainbows until owner yells pee in litter box hiss at cats the dog smells bad and all of a sudden cat goes crazy, but pose purrfectly to show my beauty but find a way to fit in tiny box, and cat snacks meow for food, then when human fills food dish, take a few bites of food and continue meowing. Hiss at vacuum cleaner milk the cow or sit on the laptop, warm up laptop with butt lick butt fart rainbows until owner yells pee in litter box hiss at cats, so step on your keyboard while you're gaming and then turn in a circle always hungry white cat sleeps on a black shirt.
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Go full screen and resize your browser.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer Andrei.
Delighted that it can't actually work, felt like an idiot after trying a million different ways to get it work.
I understand what I have to do to get the same effect now.

Comment: You're welcome, @Zeruko. Additionally, you might want to display the image with `display:block`, above the text on mobile devices. Just add it as `<img />` inside the first container and only display it on mobile. Being the same resource, it only gets loaded once, there's no overhead. I've added it to the answer.